# Django Annotate Count with MySQL creates Count on Left Outer Join with Wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql, django, annotations, count

In Django running on MySQL with MyISAM, my Count annotation on a queryset is returning incorrect results.  I've taken a look at the SQL statement and cannot figure out if it's a problem with MySQL or with my Django code.

Django model:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    ...
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="resources")
```

Code:

```
resources = Resource.objects.filter(
    ...
).annotate(
    votes=models.Count('voters')
).order_by('-votes')
print resources.query
```

SQL printed:
Something to the effect of

```
SELECT
...,
COUNT(`app_resource_voters`.`user_id`) AS `votes`
FROM `app_resource`
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN `app_resource_voters`
ON `app_resource`.`id` = `app_resource_voters`.`resource_id`
...
```

Testing the query in phpMyAdmin returns the wrong values for votes.  It actually returns the number of voters times the number of ForeignKey associations to other attributes that are present on resource (very confusing).  Do the Django and SQL look right, and would this mean that it's an issue with MySQL?  Would you recommend swapping to something other than MyISAM or swapping to PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two other possibilites you could use as a workaround.

The first one is the simpler one but less efficent: Create a method or property on your `Resource` model.

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    ...

    @property    # or @django.utils.functional.cached_property
    def votes(self):
        return self.voters.count()
```

The second is to use [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
resources = Resource.objects.filter(
    ...
).extra(
    select={
        'votes': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_resource_voters WHERE app_resource.id = app_resource_voters.resource_id'
    },
).order_by('-votes')
```

Comment: Django docs [recommend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) excatly the same way to count items in m2m relations (like in question). Are they also wrong?

Comment: Hm you are right. I didn't know that. I will have to edit my answer. In this case there should be a `GROUP BY app_resource.id` clause in the SQL.

Comment: The extra works.  The actual generated queryset is huge so I avoided the `@property` method.  For the sake of extending the code a bit, there are ways of auto-generating the table names through `model._meta.db_table`, but I'm unsure how to fetch this data for the m2m table.  @DrTyrsa, the way of the documentation worked until I added some extra filters, then it suddenly stopped.  This way through the extra clause fixed it.

Comment: Maybe you can post these other filters you did?

Comment: Many other filters...and the `Count()` worked for most of them.  The most recent edit was to add a filter checking m2m field for existence in a set.  Example: with a model `GroupA` with a m2m field in `Resource`, say "group_a", we do `Resource.objects.filter(group_a__in=group_a_set)`, where `group_a_set` is a set of resources to filter by.  Only recent change.

Comment: Hm, yes, so you have another join on that table. It makes sense that you get |votes| * |group_a| since the joins work similar to cartesian products. But that is just how relational databases work. Reading it django syntax, though, is very misleading.